# Rails 4 how to parameterize enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, slug

How to parameterize enum? I need to use the enum for parameter which has an integer value as a data type.

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum category_id: [ :hotel, :travel, :restaurant ]
end
```

**views/products/sidebar**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge"><%= Product.where(user_id: current_user).count %></span>
      <a href="<%= provider_root_path %>">All</a>
    </li>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge"><%= Product.where(category_id: category[1]).count %></span>
      <a href="<%= provider_product_category_path(category[0].parameterize) %>"><%= category[0].titleize %></a>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this line works exactly what I want:

```
<%= product_category_path(category[0].parameterize) %>
```

it produces:

```
'/product/category/travel'
```

and here is my problem:

**controllers/product_controller.rb**

```
def category
  @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:category_id]).order("created_at DESC")
  @categories = @products.category_ids
end
```

I need to change the `params[:category_id]` to integer. I have try `params[:category_id].to_i` but it always return 0.

Can anybody help? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get product successful, you need:

```
Product.where(category_id: params[:category_id].to_sym).order(anything_you_want)
```

To get strictly integer, you need to:

```
Product.category_ids[params[:category_id].to_sym]
```

Comment: now it works :) `@products = Product.where(category_id: Product.category_ids[params[:category_id].to_sym]).order("created_at DESC")` thank you so much